# Problema ao calcular porcentagem (resultado é sempre "0")

Tags: python, python-3.x

Terminei um programa em Python (aperfeiçoado com uma resposta obtida aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow), mas estou tentando incluir um cálculo de porcentagem que não está dando certo. Apesar de tudo o mais funcionar, o resultado do percentual é sempre "0".

Há algum problema no código abaixo? O arquivo .csv contém nomes de cursos de Ensino Superior e números de vagas oferecidas, candidatos inscritos e ingressos em cada um.

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
vagas = 0
inscritos = 0
ingressos = 0
arquivo = open('censo2016.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    if registro[0] == curso_desejado:
        vagas += int(registro[1])
        inscritos += int(registro[2])
        ingressos += int(registro[3])
        porcentagem = int(ingressos / vagas) * 100
print(f'O número de vagas oferecidas em {curso_desejado} é: {vagas}')
print(f'O número de inscritos em {curso_desejado} é: {inscritos}')
print(f'O número de ingressantes em {curso_desejado} é: {ingressos}')
print(f'O percentual de vagas preenchidas em {curso_desejado} é: {porcentagem}'"%")
```

O resultado para o input "Direito", por exemplo, aparece assim:

```
Qual o curso? Direito
O número de vagas oferecidas em Direito é: 245956
O número de inscritos em Direito é: 1204636
O número de ingressantes em Direito é: 206623
O percentual de vagas preenchidas em Direito é: 0%
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro no programa original está nesta linha:

```
porcentagem = int(ingressos / vagas) * 100
```

Bom, ingressos / vagas, sempre vai dar um número entre 0 e 1. Isso transformado em inteiro sempre vai pegar só a parte inteira, que é 0.
Daí você multiplica 0 por 100.

Na versão que funciona, você removeu os parenteses, e a chamada a int - 
e a conta ficou certa. Mas se quisesse um valor inteiro, é só fazer:

```
porcentagem = round((ingressos / vagas) * 100)
```

Pronto, agora temos um número entre 0 e 100 - o número entre 0 e 1 é multiplicado por 100, e então arredondado. Usar `round` aí é melhor porque não vai truncar a parte decimal: 0.7 % vai virar 1% e não 0%.

(o par de parênteses interno é só para aumentar a legibilidade, e você não ter que ficar se preocupando, ao ler a expressão, se primeiro é feita a divisão ou primeiro a conta  "vagas * 100", o que daria resultados diferentes. As regras da linguagem são claras, mas são pequenos ajustes em prol da legibilidade que fazem um programa ser mais mantível)

Answer (score 1):

Opa, agora deu certo. Aparentemente porcentagem não deve ser apresentada como número inteiro (seria essa a explicação?).

Funcionou assim:

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
vagas = 0
inscritos = 0
ingressos = 0
arquivo = open('censo2016.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    if registro[0] == curso_desejado:
        vagas += int(registro[1])
        inscritos += int(registro[2])
        ingressos += int(registro[3])
        porcentagem = ingressos / vagas * 100
print(f'O número de vagas oferecidas em {curso_desejado} é: {vagas}')
print(f'O número de inscritos em {curso_desejado} é: {inscritos}')
print(f'O número de ingressantes em {curso_desejado} é: {ingressos}')
print(f'O percentual de vagas preenchidas em {curso_desejado} é: {porcentagem:.1f}'"%")
```